# Gparted cannot increase or decrease the size when resizing a partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I am trying to resize my partition on Gparted, but I can't increase or decrease the size of partition, here is a screenshot [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGA6w.png)

What is wrong with it ?

Answer (score 0):

Login using the live USB and then try to resize it using gparted. Your partition(/dev/sda1) needs to be unmounted before they can be resized from gparted.

Comment: I'll try that and report back

Comment: Is there any simpler way ?

Comment: Please try that